# How can i rotate image and video if it was captured in landscape mode?

Tags: android, imageview

- I have an ImageView and VideoView on my screen.
- My Activity is always in a portrait mode (and i can't rotate it because of another elements).

How can i rotate image/video if it was captured in landscape mode?

Show like on this image [image: **this**]

instead of

[image: **this**]

Answer (score 0):

```
public Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // Perform matrix rotations/mirrors depending on camera that took the photo
        if (cameraCurrentID == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            float[] mirrorY = { -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
            Matrix matrixMirrorY = new Matrix();
            matrixMirrorY.setValues(mirrorY);
            matrix.postConcat(matrixMirrorY);
        }
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(),
                source.getHeight(), matrix, false);
    }
```

Comment: I don't know how to rotate video but if you use custom camera, try mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90) in prepare video recorder method.