# Is there any way to rotate only a few elements on screen rotation (instead of whole screen)?

Tags: android, rotation, screen-orientation, screen-rotation

Currently i'm trying to show image/video properly ([How can i rotate image and video if it was captured in landscape mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039186/how-can-i-rotate-image-and-video-if-it-was-captured-in-landscape-mode)) and as 1 of solution i see this one (overriding screen rotation method and prevent it for some elements).

Is it possible to do?

May be i can call rotation for elements whenever i want somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to work with a ViewStub and attach a layout to this element regarding the current screen orientation?

```
ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub);
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
   stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.landscape);
} else {
   stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.portrait);
}
```